# Why can't I add packages to flutter

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I tried to add dependencies:
english_words: ^3.1.5    To my pupsec.yaml file, when I do and try the Flutter Pub Get command I get this error: Mathiass-MacBook-Pro:startuplabs_0 mathiassoderlund$ flutter pub get
Error on line 34, column 5 of pubspec.yaml: A dependency may only have one source.
╷
34 │ ┌     sdk: flutter
35 │ │
36 │ │     dependencies:
37 │ │       flutter:
38 │ │         sdk: flutter
39 │ │
40 │ │
41 │ │     english_words: ^3.1.5
42 │ │
43 │ │ # For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
44 │ │ # following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec
45 │ │
46 │ └ # The following section is specific to Flutter.
╵

```
Running "flutter pub get" in startuplabs_0...                           
pub get failed (65;    ╵)
Mathiass-MacBook-Pro:startuplabs_0 mathiassoderlund$
```

Here is my pupspec.yaml file: [Pupspec.yaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHGmU.png)

Comment: did you check this , https://github.com/filiph/english_words/issues/5

Answer (score 1):

You write it on the wrong place, **Write it below cupertino_icons**

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

    cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
    english_words: ^3.1.5
```

Comment: Cupertino is also is dependency so why are you calling it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Use proper indentation(spaces) in front of english_words.

The code should looks like this-

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  english_words: ^3.1.5
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Yes but now I am getting this error: Please correct the pubspec.yaml file at /Users/mathiassoderlund/AndroidStudioProjects/startuplabs_0/pubspec.yaml